# Google Analytics V1 Client - Unable to change credentials type

Tags: ruby, google-oauth, google-auth-library-ruby

We are trying to use the `google-analytics-data-v1beta` Ruby client library to interact with Google Analytics V1 APIs.

However, we require permission from our web app's users so we added a consent screen (3-Legged OAuth2 flow).

The (web) example I have followed is the one in the docs for the authentication [google-auth-library-ruby](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby).

```rb
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/web_user_authorizer'
require 'googleauth/stores/redis_token_store'
require 'redis'

client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file('/path/to/client_secrets.json')
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::RedisTokenStore.new(redis: Redis.new)
authorizer = Google::Auth::WebUserAuthorizer.new(
  client_id, scope, token_store, '/oauth2callback')


get('/authorize') do
  # NOTE: Assumes the user is already authenticated to the app
  user_id = request.session['user_id']
  credentials = authorizer.get_credentials(user_id, request)
  if credentials.nil?
    redirect authorizer.get_authorization_url(login_hint: user_id, request: request)
  end
  # Credentials are valid, can call APIs
  # ...
end

get('/oauth2callback') do
  target_url = Google::Auth::WebUserAuthorizer.handle_auth_callback_deferred(
    request)
  redirect target_url
end
```

It seems we can call the Google Analytics Data V1 Beta APIs on the line where credentials are available, but when checking the [Google Analytics Data V1](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/main/google-analytics-data-v1beta/AUTHENTICATION.md) library I can't find any way to pass in the credentials above and forced to use ADC (Application Default Credentials) to authenticate, but that's only for giving permission to our own Google Account.

Snippet from the Google Analytics Data V1 Beta docs: [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/main/google-analytics-data-v1beta/AUTHENTICATION.md)

```rb
require "google/analytics/data/v1beta"

client = ::Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::AnalyticsData::Client.new do |config|
  config.credentials = "path/to/credentialfile.json"
end
```

Also, I found out that `google-apis-analyticsadmin_v1beta` library works fine with adding other credentials type, and the following worked:

```rb
credentials = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new
credentials.access_token = token # user's access token

google_analytics_admin_client = ::Google::Apis::AnalyticsadminV1beta::GoogleAnalyticsAdminService.new
google_analytics_admin_client.authorization = credentials

accounts = google_analytics_admin_client.list_accounts
```

Feels like something is missing.

---

What I tried:

I was looking for a way to pass in credentials different than ADC (Application Default Credentials).

Something similar to:

```rb
credentials = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new
credentials.access_token = access_token # User's access token

client = ::Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::AnalyticsData::Client.new do |config|
  config.credentials = credentials
end

# OR -------

user_id = request.session['user_id']
credentials = authorizer.get_credentials(user_id, request)

client = ::Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::AnalyticsData::Client.new do |config|
  config.credentials = credentials
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a working example:

```rb
credentials = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new # Can be any credentials object
credentials.access_token = access_token # User's access token

client = ::Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::AnalyticsData::Client.new do |config|
  config.credentials = credentials
end
```

This is the same snippet mentioned in the question, but it works.